# To fire an Event when the TimerCountDown gets over

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I am working on an application where I need to stat the audio file when the timercountdown gets over. But, how do I get to know that the timer countdown has been over So, that I can start playing the audio file?

Please can anybody tell me!

Thanks,
david,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use java [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class.

delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.

```
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // start your audio
            }
        }, delay);
```